# Renaming file if file name has the same index of corresponding value in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I've searched all around but I couldn't find an straightfoward answer for this:

I have a dataframe, whose `.head()` looks like this:

```
                0                jpeg         chave      Sysemp
0     OR-1101AZUL     OR-1101AZUL.jpg   OR-1101AZUL    1657.jpg
1   OR-1101AZUL-1   OR-1101AZUL-1.jpg   OR-1101AZUL  1657-1.jpg
2   OR-1101AZUL-2   OR-1101AZUL-2.jpg   OR-1101AZUL  1657-2.jpg
3    OR-1101BAZUL    OR-1101BAZUL.jpg  OR-1101BAZUL    1648.jpg
4  OR-1101BAZUL-1  OR-1101BAZUL-1.jpg  OR-1101BAZUL  1648-1.jpg
```

Here is the data as a dictionary:

```
{
    0: {
        0: "OR-1101AZUL",
        1: "OR-1101AZUL-1",
        2: "OR-1101AZUL-2",
        3: "OR-1101BAZUL",
        4: "OR-1101BAZUL-1",
    },
    "jpeg": {
        0: "OR-1101AZUL.jpg",
        1: "OR-1101AZUL-1.jpg",
        2: "OR-1101AZUL-2.jpg",
        3: "OR-1101BAZUL.jpg",
        4: "OR-1101BAZUL-1.jpg",
    },
    "chave": {
        0: "OR-1101AZUL",
        1: "OR-1101AZUL",
        2: "OR-1101AZUL",
        3: "OR-1101BAZUL",
        4: "OR-1101BAZUL",
    },
    "Sysemp": {
        0: "1657.jpg",
        1: "1657-1.jpg",
        2: "1657-2.jpg",
        3: "1648.jpg",
        4: "1648-1.jpg",
    },
}
```

and then I have a folder, with images in it. In this folder, the names have the 'jpeg' column name template. I made a script that should iterate through the jpeg column and, if this name is found within the folder, the script should replace the former name to the new name, that is the index equivalent on 'Sysemp' column. If the name its not found, the script should ignore and continue to iterate:

```
for i in df_nomesImagens['jpeg']:
    for j in df_nomesImagens['Sysemp']:
        for k in files:
            if i != k or i not in files:
                pass
            else:
                if i == k and j not in files:
                    os.rename(k, j)
                else:
                    pass
```

But it is not working, I'm recieving `FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2]` or it renames the files ignoring the index equivalence

How can I rename the files according to the same index, using the new name in 'Sysemp' column?

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: _it renames the files ignoring the index equivalence_ What do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loops are the main issue, they shouldn't be nested like that. Your code iterates through every combination of the values in the `"jpeg"` and `"Sysemp"` columns, which explains why some files were being renamed to the wrong value. Try walking through the execution of the code on paper, it'll make things more obvious.

Here is a straightforward solution, using pathlib:

```py
import pathlib

import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data={
        "jpeg": {
            0: "OR-1101AZUL.jpg",
            1: "OR-1101AZUL-1.jpg",
            2: "OR-1101AZUL-2.jpg",
            3: "OR-1101BAZUL.jpg",
            4: "OR-1101BAZUL-1.jpg",
        },
        "Sysemp": {
            0: "1657.jpg",
            1: "1657-1.jpg",
            2: "1657-2.jpg",
            3: "1648.jpg",
            4: "1648-1.jpg",
        },
    }
)

folder_path = pathlib.Path("")  # path goes here

name_map = dict(df.itertuples(index=False, name=None))

for curr_path in folder_path.iterdir():
    new_name = name_map.get(curr_path.name)
    if new_name is not None:
        curr_path.rename(curr_path.with_name(new_name))
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not running your loops side by side.  Essentially you are iterating through every `Sysemp` for each item of `jpeg`, which wouldn't give you a match.

It would be easier to create a mapping dict and use that to translate your file names:

```
mapper = df[['jpeg', 'Sysemp']].set_index('jpeg')['Sysemp'].to_dict()

# result:
# {'OR-1101AZUL.jpg': '1657.jpg',
#  'OR-1101AZUL-1.jpg': '1657-1.jpg',
#  'OR-1101AZUL-2.jpg': '1657-2.jpg',
#  'OR-1101BAZUL.jpg': '1648.jpg',
#  'OR-1101BAZUL-1.jpg': '1648-1.jpg'}
```

And then just iterate through your files:

```
for f in files:
    new_name = mapper.get(f)
    # dict.get returns None by default if no match found
    # essentially equal to mapper.get(f, None)

    if new_name: # if there's a match
        os.rename(f, new_name)

del mapper # free up the extra memory
```

Note: the `os.rename` is happening *relatively*.  If your `files` are not directly within your working directory, you will run into issues.  You might want to use `os.path` to create absolute paths to your files instead.